# UI-Element (Image) turns black in Game view, but is normal in Scene view

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, shader

I want to make a starting screen linking to my menu. Using `Shader Graph` (unlit Shader) I created a little animation, where the background (an image with the material + Shader) pulsates.

I searched for different solutions, but so far nothing helped. I tried changing the Near/Far values at the main camera. Every label is visible.

Hierarchy

[image: Hierarchy]

Scene View

[image: Scene View]

Game View

[image: Game View]

My Smartphone (Samsung Galaxy S3 neo, running Android 4.4.2)
//EDIT: I forgot to mention that the screen was kinda buggy while capturing the screenshot, but I couldn't capture this.

[image: My Smartphone (Samsung Galaxy S3 neo, running Android 4.4.2)]

the shader in shadergraph

[image: the shader in shadergraph]

I hope this helps. I really don't know what to do since it seems like a graphic issue of some kind.

Thanks in advance.

//UPDATE: I checked (using the Developer Mode on Android) if the screen is updating at the expected rate (presumably almost every frame) and yes, it is. I couldn't see a difference, but something is working.

//UPDATE2: Using the Frame Debugger I found out, that it casts shadows. Since my new question (How to disable shadows in an unlit shader?) differs from my original one, I will close it.

Comment: Have you had a look at your scene in 3D view to make sure it's definitely in the right place?

Comment: Is this necessary? I'm not sure, since picture and button (and Canvas) are UI-Elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Frame Debugger I found out, that the black color applies when the shadows of the shader are applied.

I hope this helps.